# Lorsqu'on parle des Pays-Bas, doit-on utiliser le singulier ou le pluriel ?

Tags: grammaire, pluriel, toponymes

J'aurai une présentation sur Les Pays-Bas, mais je ne sais pas si on utilise le singulier ou le pluriel pour parler des Pays-Bas.

Par exemple :

Dit-on :

> Les Pays-Bas sont un petit pays. Ils sont 15 fois plus petits que la France.

ou

> Les Pays-Bas est un petit pays. Il est 15 fois plus petit que la France.

Answer (score 6):

Le verbe de la première phrase doit s'accorder avec son sujet, « **les Pays-Bas** », qui est au pluriel, donc :

> Les Pays-Bas **sont** un petit pays. Ils sont quinze fois plus petits que la France.

Le sujet de la deuxième phrase peut reprendre soit « les Pays-Bas » soit « pays ». Dans ce deuxième cas, il sera au singulier.

> Les Pays-Bas sont un petit pays. **Il est** quinze fois plus **petit** que la France.

Answer (score 3):

Le [Wikipédia sur les Pays-Bas](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pays-Bas) semble un bon exemple pour répondre cette question.

Donc, **dans ton exemple, le pluriel est utilisé**.

Dans le Wikipédia, afin d'éviter les répétitions, les utilisations comme:

`Le pays` ou `Le Royaume des Pays-Bas`, etc. sont tout simplement au singulier.

Answer (score -2):

"Les Pays-Bas est un petit pays. Il est 15 fois plus petit que la France" est la bonne réponse.

Il s'agit d'un seul pays et non pas d'un ensemble de pays comme par exemple " les pays de l'union européenne"

Le terme Hollande est aussi utilisé, par synecdoque, pour désigner l'ensemble des Pays-Bas.